# Print a multi-line message with NLog

Tags: nlog

Is it possible with NLog to emit a multi-line message such that each line is formatted according to the current layout? E.g.

```
2015-12-17 11:37:38.0845 | 64 | INFO | -----------------------------------
2015-12-17 11:37:38.0845 | 64 | INFO | Statistics:
2015-12-17 11:37:38.0845 | 64 | INFO |   Crawling Requests   46887 /min
2015-12-17 11:37:38.0845 | 64 | INFO |   Stored Documents    9910 /min
2015-12-17 11:37:38.0845 | 64 | INFO | -----------------------------------
```

Alternatively, is it possible with NLog to emit multiple messages as a single, non-interrupted block in a multithreaded environment?

Answer (score 8):

You can do all this from your config.

```
<variable name="statData" value="${longdate} | 64 | ${level} | "/>
<variable name="line" value="-----------------------------------"/>
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="Console"
        name="Console"
        layout="
        ${statData}${line}${newline}
        ${statData}Statistics:${newline}
        ${statData}  Crawling Requests   46887 /min ${newline}
        ${statData}  Stored Documents    9910 /min ${newline}
        ${statData}${line}${newline}"/>
```

Wasn't exactly sure what your 64 was or where you were getting your per minute data. Probably a variable or something your inserting.This should also work if you are logging to a file not the console.

As for your second question, if you are wanting a single log message from multiple threads I think you would have to do that on the code side. You would have to collect your threads, get your log data you want and send it 1 time to nLog. I might be misunderstanding though

Comment: Thanks for your input. The statistics message is generated procedurally so I can't format the message in the config file. As for my second question, what I'm looking for is a way to write N messages to NLog in a way that guarantees that these messages will be written at once, without other messages coming from other threads being interspersed.

Comment: Are you saying the number of lines in your statistics could vary based off what you generate? I tried using the replace-newlines layout render, but I'm having a weird issue. It seems like the replacement won't accept another layout render, just text. You might have better results. There is also a regex replace layout. Basically I was going for replacing each line return from your message with your stat data
layout="${replace-newlines:replacement=${statData}:${message}}"/>

Comment: Yes, the statistics block is entirely built by code, and in particular the number of lines could vary. My question is really a general one: how to output N lines of log at once, atomically. I didn't know the `replace-newlines` layout renderer. It seems like it could be the solution, if it would work.

Comment: How can this be helpfull?

Answer (score 3):

There does not appear to be existing functionally to do this yet (as of NLog 4.2.3). A potential solution is to create your own wrapper layout renderer to improve the functionality of the *replace-newlines* renderer.

So *replace-newlines* and *replace* wrappers will not take layout renderers in their replacement strings. Looking at the NLog source for other wrappers, renderers, and targets, a `Layout` type property can be used to accept a string with (or without) layout renderers. The built in replace wrappers fail when provided a layout renderer because their `Replacement` property type is `string`. The xml parser is only looking for plain text but the } of a provided layout renderer prematurely ends the *replace-newline* wrapper.

The following custom wrapper changes the replacement type from `string` to `Layout`. The replacement layout then needs to be rendered by calling its `Render` method with some context (`LogEventInfo`). This can be done in the overridden `Append` method where `LogEventInfo` is available. The rendered output can be saved off for later usage in the `Transform` method.

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers.Wrappers;
using NLog.Layouts;

namespace My.Namespace
{
    [LayoutRenderer("replace-newlines-withlayout")]
    [ThreadAgnostic]
    public class ReplaceNewLinesFormatLayoutRendererWrapper : WrapperLayoutRendererBase
    {
        private string m_replacementString = " ";

        public ReplaceNewLinesFormatLayoutRendererWrapper()
        {
            // Changed from
            // Replacement = " ";
            Replacement = Layout.FromString(" ");
        }

        // Changed from
        // public string Replacement { get; set; }
        public Layout Replacement { get; set; }

        // Override Append in order to render the replacement.
        protected override void  Append(StringBuilder builder, NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            // Render...
            m_replacementString = Replacement.Render(logEvent);

            // The base functionality of append is fine.
            base.Append(builder, logEvent);
        }   

        // Called from base.Append()
        protected override string Transform(string text)
        {
            // Changed from 
            // return text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Replacement);

            // Now just put in the rendered replacement string.
            return text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, m_replacementString);
        }
    }
}
```

And then, for example, use it as

```xml
<target
    ...
    layout=${replace-newlines-withlayout:replacement=${newline}${time}:${message}}
    ... 
    />
```

In this simplified case, assuming ${message} has line breaks, each new line will be prefixed with a time stamp. Just replace ${time} with the desired prefix layout.