# Print a multi-line message with NLog.Extensions.Logging (1.6.1)

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm developing a .NET Core 3.1 console application with NLog.Extensions.Logging (v1.6.1) and would like to print a message containing multiple lines.  I followed an example previously provided on StackOverflow using a wrapper layout renderer, copied below.  I see how new lines are being replaced; however, the beginning of the multi-line message (i.e. the first line) is not being prefixed (?)

Output from Example looks like this:

```
line 1> Hello world 
line 2> 19:30:45.2313 Hello World , again
```

## Previously Provided Example Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers.Wrappers;
using NLog.Layouts;

namespace My.Namespace
{
    [LayoutRenderer("replace-newlines-withlayout")]
    [ThreadAgnostic]
    public class ReplaceNewLinesFormatLayoutRendererWrapper : WrapperLayoutRendererBase
    {
        private string m_replacementString = " ";

        public ReplaceNewLinesFormatLayoutRendererWrapper()
        {
            // Changed from
            // Replacement = " ";
            Replacement = Layout.FromString(" ");
        }

        // Changed from
        // public string Replacement { get; set; }
        public Layout Replacement { get; set; }

        // Override Append in order to render the replacement.
        protected override void  Append(StringBuilder builder, NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            // Render...
            m_replacementString = Replacement.Render(logEvent);

            // The base functionality of append is fine.
            base.Append(builder, logEvent);
        }   

        // Called from base.Append()
        protected override string Transform(string text)
        {
            // Changed from 
            // return text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Replacement);

            // Now just put in the rendered replacement string.
            return text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, m_replacementString);
        }
    }
}
```

NLog.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XSD manual extracted from package NLog.Schema: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Schema-->
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="NLog NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\console-example-internal.log"
      internalLogLevel="Info" >

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="target1" fileName="c:\temp\console-example.log"
        layout="${replace-newlines-withlayout:replacement=${newline}${time}:${message}}" />
    <target xsi:type="ColoredConsole" name="target2"
        layout="${replace-newlines-withlayout:replacement=${newline}${time}:${message}}" />
    />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="target1,target2" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Example:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var ReplaceNewLinesFormatLayoutRendererWrapper = new ReplaceNewLinesFormatLayoutRendererWrapper();
            ReplaceNewLinesFormatLayoutRendererWrapper.Register<NLogTest.ReplaceNewLinesFormatLayoutRendererWrapper>("replace-newlines-withlayout");

            Logger.Info($"Hello world {Environment.NewLine} Hello World , again");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex, "yeah, here again");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I followed an example previously provided on StackOverflow...* It would be helpful if you put a link to the answer you are referring to.

Comment: To be sure, please include the relevant config and the examples that work and doesn't work - thanks!

Comment: Here's the link that I was referencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333794/print-a-multi-line-message-with-nlog

Comment: Edited original post and added Nlog.config, Example and Example output.  Thanks!

Comment: "Output from Example" is the current behavior and not the desired isn't? You don't want the "line 1 >" etc isn't?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. There is no newline at the beginning of the string?

Comment: That's right, the "Output from Example" is the current behavior and not desired.  And yes, don't want to want "line 1 >" - I added that to indicate the individual lines (sorry for possible confusion).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `Transform` is called before `Append`, and your  `Transform` is depended of `Append`.

Luckily nowadays there is a better `Transform` to override, the one that will also include the `LogEventInfo` as parameter. (NLog 4.5+)

So you could drop the current Append and Transform overwrites, and replace with:

```
protected override string Transform(LogEventInfo logEvent, string text)
{
    // Render...
    var replacementString = Replacement.Render(logEvent);

    // Now just put in the rendered replacement string.
    return text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, replacementString);
}
```

Full code (after some cleaning):

```
using System;
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers.Wrappers;
using NLog.Layouts;

namespace My.Namespace
{
    [LayoutRenderer("replace-newlines-withlayout")]
    [ThreadAgnostic]
    public class ReplaceNewLinesFormatLayoutRendererWrapper : WrapperLayoutRendererBase
    {
        public Layout Replacement { get; set; } = " ";

        protected override string Transform(LogEventInfo logEvent, string text)
        {
            // Render...
            var replacementString = Replacement.Render(logEvent);

            // Now just put in the rendered replacement string.
            return text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, replacementString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you .  However, after making the changes outlined above, I'm still getting the same results as I did with my the original code (?)  My example program is calling Transform(LogEventInfo logEvent, string text) too.  In fact, it is called twice in the example.  Separately but related,I needed to override 'protected override string Transform(string text)', defined in WrapperLayoutRendererBase, to satisfy the abstract.

Comment: Would `return replacementString + text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, replacementString);` (maybe with some more checks) fix this? Or don't I understand the case?

Comment: You're right with the transform override. Will fix that.

Comment: Thank-you.  By adding returning "replacementString + text.Replace(Environment.NewLine,  replacementString);"  the first line is being prefixed but now there's an extra blank line before it due to the replacement string itself.  What I don't understand at a high-level is that Transform is being called twice with the same string, interpolation of "$"Hello world {Environment.NewLine} Hello World , again".  Thanks again.